# Unable to install and use gRPC C/C++ on windows 10 with VS2017

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, grpc

I know the question I am asking here seems a bit silly but it is still an open ended question and will definitely help a lot of folks.

Problem :- What could be the way to install and use gRPC C/C++ in Visual Studio 2017 and windows 10 64 bit.

The documentation says to use CMAKE but providing very less information on how to actually build gRPC.

If anyone could please guide me step by step how to install gRPC would be very helpful to me and others who are new to gRPC and trying to build it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Don't need go through the hassles compiling it, gRPC is available via NuGet.

Comment: @J.Doe thanks for your input,Could you please point how what are all the packages that needed to be downloaded from NuGet

Comment: search for grpc.cpp

Comment: @J.Doe thanks a lot it is building successfully but not linking correctly do i need to pass linker directory path manually after installing from nuget ?

Comment: Have you linked against `grpc++.lib`, `gpr.lib`?

Comment: @J.Doe since I am a newbie I don't know how to find those *. lib file and how to link them in vs2017. The last words of help from your could make the process complete. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: [Right click on Project] => [Properties]; Tree to the left: [Configuragtion Properties] => [Linker] => [Input]; Right side: Dropdown of [Additional Dependencies] => [Edit...]; Add `grpc++.lib` and `gpr.lib` there. Make sure to do that for all configurations and platforms (dropdowns at the top of the properties dialog) you want to build your project for.

Comment: @J.Doe I have tried your suggestion but still it is not working

Comment: What exactly is "not working"?

Comment: @J.Doe It always shows below error while building in VS2017
GRPCServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall grpc::ServerBuilder::ServerBuilder(void)" (??0ServerBuilder@grpc@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\30183393\source\repos\GRPCTest\Debug\GRPCServer.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Is there another way by now? The grpc and protobuf versions in NuGet are very outdated for C++...

Answer (score 4):

I recently had issues with this myself and would like to present my solution, although the question is a little old.

There is a working `vcpkg` package available, but its version is outdated. Therefore I build and installed gRPC on Windows from source using Visual Studio 2017. The official [documentation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md) gives some hints, but is pretty vague in the details. I will list all steps below, some are copied from said documentation:

### Prerequisites

- **Visual Studio** (2015 or above should do)
- **Git**
- **CMake** (make sure to add CMake to the system PATH during installation)

### Get gRPC

1. Clone gRPC repository:

   ```
   git clone -b RELEASE_TAG_HERE https://github.com/grpc/grpc
   ```

   Replace `RELEASE_TAG_HERE` with the release tag of your choice, e.g. `v1.42.0` is the latest right now.
2. Load its dependencies:

   ```
   cd grpc
   git submodule update --init
   ```

### Build gRPC from source

1. Create a build directory and go to it:

   ```
   mkdir .build
   cd .build
   ```
2. Generate Visual Studio project structure with CMake:

   for Visual Studio 2017:

   ```
   cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017"
   ```

   or for Visual Studio 2019:

   ```
   cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 16 2019"
   ```

   or for Visual Studio 2022:

   ```
   cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 17 2022"
   ```

   Specify a specific target platform with the `-A` option, e.g. `Win32`, `x64`,`ARM` or `ARM64`.
3. Open the newly created solution `grpc.sln` (can be found in the `.build` directory) in Visual Studio.
4. Select the desired "Solution Configuration" (Debug, Release, ...) in Visual Studio and build the solution.

### Install gRPC

This was the hard part to figure out, although it is fairly easy.

1. Start Visual Studio **with administrator privileges** and load `grpc.sln`.
2. In the "Solution Explorer", search for the project `INSTALL`.
3. Build the `INSTALL` project.
4. gRPC is now installed to:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\grpc
   ```
5. Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\grpc\bin` to your systems PATH.

### Use gRPC in your project

1. Add gRPC header files:

   Right click on project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories

   Edit this property and add the gRPC include directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\grpc\include`.
2. Add gRPC library directory:
   Right click on project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories

   Edit this property and add the gRPC library directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\grpc\lib\`.
3. Add gRPC libraries:

   Right click on project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

   Edit this property and add all libraries from the gRPC library directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\grpc\lib\`).

   **There will be errors when building the project!** Apparently, some libraries are present in different versions. You have to choose one of the versions for each library. As of gRPC `v1.42.0` (Release Build), these libraries are:

   - `grpc.lib` vs. `grpc_unsecure.lib`
   - `grpc++.lib` vs. `grpc++_unsecure.lib`
   - `libprotobuf.lib` vs. `libprotobuf-lite.lib`
   - `libprotoc.lib` seems to be included in `libprotobuf.lib`
   - `zlib.lib` vs. `zlibstatic.lib`

   Another option is link the libraries with preprocessor directives `#pragma comment(lib, LIBRARY_HERE)` into your project. Thus, the unused version can be commented out.
4. Now, your project should build without errors. Make sure you use the same "Solution Configuration" (Debug, Release) as you used for the gRPC build.

I hope this rather detailed guide helps you guys!

Comment: Question, there are like 80 .libs in C:\Program Files (x86)\grpc\lib\. Do you include those one by one in step 3?

Comment: I am not aware of any other way. To not have to copy each .lib name individually, i used FreeCommander to copy only the filenames to clipboard:
1. Select all the libs in FreeCommander
2. Edit -> Copy to clipboard -> Copy item name to clipboard

Comment: I see... My next question is, how do you include .proto files into your project and build them? I followed your steps and I can build my own project with the grpc libs included.

Comment: The "protoc" compiler is used to compile the .proto files. You can find it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\grpc\bin`.
The compiler has to be invoked from the commandline. You can find out more on the required command line options at: [https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#invocation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#invocation).
You could even integrate the protoc commandline call into Visual Studio via a custom build step (which compiles your .proto every time it has changed).